# Grails jdbcsqlexception column not found

Tags: database, grails, controller, grails-orm

I'm trying to create a function that will allow user to like/dislike a process in my Grails app. I've done it before for articles and it's working perfectly. For some reason, when I try to do it the same way for processes, I got this exception:

```
Message
    Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error evaluating expression [businessProcess?.getLikedCount()] on line [18]: could not prepare statement
Caused by
    Column "THIS_.LIKED" does not exist Column "THIS_.LIKED" not found; SQL statement: select count(*) as y0_ from business_process_like this_ where this_.liked=? limit ? [42122-191]
```

This is my domain class for `BusinessProcessLike` code:

```
class BusinessProcessLike {

    BusinessProcess businessProcess

    ServiceUser serviceUser

    boolean liked;

    static constraints = {
        businessProcess nullable: false
        serviceUser nullable: false
        liked nullable: false
    }
}
```

In comparison, the ArticleLike looks like this:

```
class ArticleLike {

    Article article

    ServiceUser serviceUser

    boolean liked;

    static constraints = {
        article nullable: false
        serviceUser nullable: false
    }

}
```

What could be the reason for this? I've already checked some posts about the same problem, but it always was the fact that word being used was reserved by the database, but here is not the case.

Also, this is the method that causes the exception:

```
  @Transactional
    def businessProcessLikeAction(){
        ServiceUser user = springSecurityService.currentUser
        BusinessProcess businessProcess = BusinessProcess.findById(params.getIdentifier())
        //line below throws the exception
        BusinessProcessLike processLike = BusinessProcessLike.findByBusinessProcessAndServiceUser(businessProcess, user);

        if(!processLike){
            processLike = new BusinessProcessLike(businessProcess: businessProcess, serviceUser: user)
        }
        processLike.liked = Boolean.valueOf(params.status)
        processLike.save()
        redirect(action: "showBusinessProcessList")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, just in case someone had the same problem - the reason why it threw the exception was the fact that there's been one object in the table created prior to adding the new column, so the problem was not within the code, but within the wrong chronology of my actions. Anytime I tried to operate on the given table I had the exception, because GORM wanted to do something with the column that existed in the table, but not in the previously created record.